# Moderation: can a moderator also have a main effect?

Tags: interaction

For my research, participants will have to read an article that either talks positive or negative about the colonial past of their country. In addition, we expect that their level of ideology (on a continuous scale) will have a moderator effect. So:

- DV: evaluation of colonial history
- IV: article (positive, negative)
- moderator: ideology

However, I'm already struggling to set up the hypothesis: I expect that the moderator will influence the effect of the article on the participants' evaluation of their colonial history. But what about the main effects? My intention tells me that the ideology will also have a main effect on the DP, but if I understood correctly, usually the main effects of a moderator are not really considered (only the main effects from an IV). Any suggestions? Is it 'allowed' to do a hypothesis which says that there's an moderation effect, but also a main effect? I don't really want to change my design as I have it already discussed with my supervisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, then yes, that's a moderator effect and yes, you should include it as a main effect as well.

Your model would be:

Evaluation = Article tone + ideology + article tone*ideology

In statistics, moderation is another word for interaction and it is almost always a good idea to include both parts of the interaction as main effects.

It is possible that I am misunderstanding your question, though.  You should look into mediators and make sure that you really mean moderation and not mediation (it's easy to get confused).

Comment: Thank you! No, you understood my question perfectly, I just have trouble expressing myself in English, especially in stats ;-)
I did the analysis and the results show that both the article tone + ideology are significant as a main effect. The interaction however is not significant. How should I interpret it? Ideology is not a moderator, but rather an IV?

Comment: There are lots of threads here about interactions moderations.  Just search for moderation.